# Most efficient way of finding the next element in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I've got a system in which I often (but not constantly) have to find the next item in a tuple. I'm currently doing this like so:

```
mytuple = (2,6,4,8,7,9,14,3)
currentelement = 4
def f(mytuple, currentelement):
    return mytuple[mytuple.index(currentelement) + 1]
nextelement = f(mytuple, currentelement)
```

All elements are unique and I am not stuck with the tuple, I can make it something else earlier in the program if needed.

Since I need to do this **a lot**, I was wondering whether there is any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: All numbers are unique?

Comment: If you are stuck with the data structure (i.e. a tuple), then no. A linear search is all you can do.

Comment: Yes, all elements are unique, but actually, it are not numbers in my program, but strings. To simplify the example I just made it numbers here..

Comment: A dict has O(1) lookups, but for small tuples, it might be faster to do a linear search anyway. It will depend on the Python implementation what size tuples are still faster than dicts

Comment: I've got tuples of about a million items, so I think a dict will be a vast improvement of my program.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dict here, dicts provide `O(1)` lookup compared to `list.index` which is an `O(N)` operation.

And this will work for strings as well.

```
>>> lis = (2,6,4,8,7,9,14,3)
>>> dic = dict(zip(lis, lis[1:]))
>>> dic[4]
8
>>> dic[7]
9
>>> dic.get(100, 'not found') #dict.get can handle key errors
'not found'
```

A memory efficient version to create the above dict:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> lis = (2,6,4,8,7,9,14,3)
>>> it1 = iter(lis)
>>> it2 = iter(lis)
>>> next(it2)
2
>>> dict(izip(it1,it2))
{2: 6, 4: 8, 6: 4, 7: 9, 8: 7, 9: 14, 14: 3}
```

Comment: You sir, are brilliant and an allround awesome person. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to build an *index* using a dictionary:

```
# The list
>>> lis = (2,6,4,8,7,9,14,3)

# build the index
>>> index = dict(zip(lis, range(len(lis))))
>>> index
{2: 0, 3: 7, 4: 2, 6: 1, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 5, 14: 6}

# Retrieve position by using the index
>>> index[6]
1
>>> lis[index[6]+1]
4
```

If your list change over time, you will have to rebuild the index. For a more memory efficient solution, you might prefer using `izip` instead of `zip̀   as suggested in an other answer.